# Coupled 4th Order (2x2nd order) ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

For constants $L$, $C$, $M$, $E_0$ and $\omega$, we have the two coupled ODEs:

$$L \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} +\frac{1}{C}x+M\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = E_0\sin(\omega t)  $$
$$L \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} +\frac{1}{C}y+M\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} =0$$

I am looking to solve in order to get equations for $x$ and $y$.
There is a fairly obvious symmetry to the problem, but dealing with the fact that both second derivatives appear in each equation proved troubling.

By adding the two equations we can arrive at the appealing
$$(L+M)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}[x+y] = \frac{1}{C}[x+y]$$

(ignoring the inhomogeneous term for now)
which can be solved trivially for $x+y$, but without any way to get $x-y$ or something equivalent I figured this line of thinking was useless.

Rearranging the second equation for $d^2y/dt^2$ and subbing into the first does not decouple them either.

I lastly thought of getting all the second derivatives on the LHS, then applying the inverse of   $\begin{matrix} L & M \\ M & L \end{matrix}$ to both sides get just a single second derivative in each equation, but again this seemed pretty tedious.

I am pretty sure I know a rather contrived way to "brute force" the answer using the above, but since the equations are particularly symmetric I was wondering if there might be a trick that I'm missing. Many thanks.

Comment: Substitute $u=x+y$ and solve, then do $w=x-y$ and solve, then you’d have a linear system of equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting the bottom equation from the top yields an expression with (x-y) on both sides, which can be used to arrive at a solution using the mentioned (x+y) solution.